# Render title attribute for asp.net textbox

Tags: asp.net, html

I want to add tooltips to a form on my site. I am using the jQuery tools library. The tooltips show the content of the title attribute of an html input. Is there a way to make the asp.net textbox render out the title attribute in the html input it creates?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would do something like `TextBox1.Attributes.Add("title", "Some title value");`

Answer (score 10):

Since title is a global attribute, according to the [W3C HTML language specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.title), I would have expected a title property in the System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.

However, Microsoft appears to have chosen a more 'appropriate' name for this property: *Tooltip*.

If you specify this property:

```
var label = new Label();
label.ToolTip = "tooltip";
label.Text = "text";
Controls.Add(label);
```

it will render:

```
<span title="tooltip">text</span>
```

which is just what you wanted.

Seeing that Tooltip is a property of the base WebControl, I assume that it will render as a title attribute for all WebControl classes.

Comment: Thank you very much for this information. I am slowly transitioning to asp.net (vb), and this sample code is what I needed, as I love showing a tooltip when the mouse hovers over the span. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
Textbox.Attributes.Add("title","My text");
```

The `.Attributes.Add("Attribute Name", "Attribute Value")` lets you add most attributes to most controls, but always use the native property if available.

Answer (score 4):

By far the easiest way is:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" title="My Title" />
```

Which renders

```
<input type="text" title="My Title" />
```

This also works with `style` etc, etc.